# I’m thinking about what happened. I often think about it

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Is it possible to use "I'm thinking" & "I often think" in real life if we speak about the same thing right now?

> **I’m thinking** about what happened. **I often think** about it.

I have them in my grammar book. If I understand right, we use "think" in the second sentence only because of "often". If there is no "often", we would use the continuous in the second sentence. Right?

Comment: The construction is perfectly idiomatic. Yes, the second sentence requires a modifier such as often/frequently. Your first sentence already uses the continuous form.  Repeating it would not make sense.

Comment: @Ronald Sole, If I understand right, the same meaning we can say with one sentence: *"I often think about what happened."* I don't see much difference.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly say that but it omits the statement that you are thinking about it now.

Comment: Generally you're right - you need "often" or "sometimes" or something like that in the second sentence. But in the right context, with the right intonation, you could imagine "often" being omitted from the second sentence. In that case, the frequency of the thinking (whether it be often, or sometimes, or occasionally) would be unclear. "I think about what happened" would be more common on its own (i.e. without being preceded by the first sentence). In any case, you would never say "I think about" something to indicate that you're thinking about it right now, though.